# Read/write Data into Cassandra using hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra

I have been trying to integrate hadoop with cassandra.

Already Runned wordcount example.

But I need sample code to connect hadoop with cassandra with step by using hector.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/rastrick/presentation-12982302) and the code samples on the associated github site.  It's for Cassandra 1.1, but it will walk you through each step.